# How can I add audio effect to the file from remote server (while streaming this audio file) with like "TheAmazingAudioEngine" framework?

Tags: ios, audio, audio-streaming, audioeffect

I'm making an audio equaliser with the "TheAmazingAudioEngine" framework. It seems that I can not add effect to audio while streaming it. The AEAudioFilePlayer will be nil if I init it with remote path as below:

```
    NSURL *remoteFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://demo.mp3"];
    self.player = [AEAudioFilePlayer audioFilePlayerWithURL:remoteFileUrl
                                            audioController:_audioController
                                                      error:NULL];
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Must I download that audio file first and then add effect? Any other frameworks are OK. Thank you.